# Single.php category entries not showing right colours

Tags: single, categories

I am trying to implement a way of having different colours for different categories in single.php. So, I have created a colour Picker field with Advanced Custom Fields and this field shows on each category page. Then the end user can choose a colour for each category in each category page where this colour picker field is present. After that the only thing I want to get the colours the end user chooses are the category links on my single.php.

At the moment I have it working fine if I only have one category. However, when I assign more than one category to the post they all become the same colour as the last category assigned.

Here is my code:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');

if( !empty($terms) ) {

    $term = array_shift($terms);
    $category_color = get_field('category_color', $term );
}

$post_categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';

if ( $post_categories ) {

    foreach( $post_categories as $post_category ) {
        $output .= '<li class="meta-category">';
            $output .= '<a style="color:' . $category_color . ';" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $post_category->term_id ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'mytheme' ), $post_category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $post_category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    echo trim( $output, $separator );
}
```

And to illustrate better the problem I am facing here are some images of my entry categories on my single.php:

[image: Here I have the aciform category, for example, which has been assigned the font colour of red. On its own it is red as it should be]

[image: Here I have the beauty category, for example, which has been assigned the font colour of blue. On its own it is blue as it should be]

[image: And here I have assigned those two categories to the same post. And the expected result should be Aciform - red and Beauty - blue. But for some reason they both show as blue..]

**Image 1** - Here I have the aciform category, for example, which has been assigned the font colour of red. On its own it is red as it should be

**Image 2** - Here I have the beauty category, for example, which has been assigned the font colour of blue. On its own it is blue as it should be

**Image 3** - And here I have assigned those two categories to the same post. And the expected result should be Aciform - red and Beauty - blue. But for some reason they both show as blue..

I have been struggling with this for awhile and can't seem to find a solution. I guess it might even be something really simple I am missing but after so much time I just can't see it.

Comment: `$category_color` in your output ( loop ) is an array. You need to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be running the first piece of code inside your `foreach` loop. What you are currently doing is to get all the post terms, get the first term object, then passing the custom field value of that term into your `foreach` loop for every post term.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$post_categories = get_the_category();
if ( $post_categories ) {
    $separator = ' ';
    $output    = '';
    foreach( $post_categories as $post_category ) {
        $category_color = get_field( 'category_color', $post_category );
        $output .= '<li class="meta-category">';
            $output .= '<a style="color:' . $category_color . ';" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $post_category ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'mytheme' ), $post_category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $post_category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    echo trim( $output, $separator );
}
```

Just a note, always pass the whole term object to `get_term_link()` and `get_category_link()` If you pass the ID or slug to these functions, they will make another db call to get the term object, which is totally unnecessary. If you pass the term object (*which you already have*), no extra db calls are made, so this way you save a lot on resources, specially if you have plenty posts

### EDIT

You can also build an array and use implode to display your string

```
$post_categories = get_the_category();
if ( $post_categories ) {
    $separator = ' ';
    $output    = [];
    foreach( $post_categories as $post_category ) {
        $category_color = get_field( 'category_color', $post_category );
        $output[] = '<li class="meta-category">
                         <a style="color:' . $category_color . ';" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $post_category ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'mytheme' ), $post_category->name ) ) . '"> 
                             ' . esc_html( $post_category->name ) . '
                         </a>
                    </li>';
    }

    if ( $output )
        echo implode( $separator, $output );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe I didn't see this. Thank you ;)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: I have asked another question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219965/colour-main-navigation-categories). Was wondering if you could help.